# Specify font location in Lambda running Corretto

Tags: java, aws-lambda, fonts

Anybody knows how to configure font location in AWS Lambda running under Corretto 8?  The Amz
Linux 2 doesn't have any font libs or fonts.  I was able to resolve the missing libs and
missing fontconfig.properties by putting them in /opt/libs and set env var -
Dsun.awt.fontconfig.  Now it's  not finding the fonts even thought I've tried to put them in
several places.

```java
SXSSFSheet sheet = sxssfWorkbook.createSheet(sheetName);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.FcFontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(FcFontManager.java:76)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:443)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:386)
    at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
    at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:491)
    at java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2064)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:470)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:531)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:273)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.AutoSizeColumnTracker.<init> 
    (AutoSizeColumnTracker.java:117)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.<init>(SXSSFSheet.java:82)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:684)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:705)
```